# How to cancel skill's Dialog from Virtual Assistant while using MS Bot Framework V4

Tags: botframework, bots, chatbot, direct-line-botframework

**We are using bot-framework version 4.x**

```
"botbuilder": "4.11.0",
"botbuilder-ai": "4.11.0",
"botbuilder-applicationinsights": "4.11.0",
"botbuilder-azure": "4.11.0",
"botbuilder-dialogs": "4.11.0",
"botbuilder-lg": "4.11.0",
"botbuilder-testing": "4.11.0",
"botframework-config": "4.11.0",
"botframework-connector": "4.11.0"
```

**Case**

We need to start a Dialog in Virtual Assistant and cancel any ongoing Skill dialog (If any)

Example

LiveChat - part of Virtual Assistant
CreateIncidentDialog - part of skill

Suppose we are in the middle of CreateIncidentDialog and the user wants to start LiveChat. We are supposed to start LiveChat and cancel current CreateIncidentDialog.

**Sample Code**

```
MainDialog.ts in Virtual Assistant
```

If current Dialog is a part of skill, we are starting a dialog with activity.type as EVENT for skill.

```
switch (gIntent) {
 case 'Escalate': {
       // Checking if current Dialog is a part of Skill
       if (isSkill) {
            const activity: Activity = innerDc.context.activity;
            if ((activity.value === null || activity.value === undefined)) {
                 activity.value = { userState: userProfile };
            };
            activity.type = ActivityTypes.Event;
            activity.name = "liveChat";
            const skillDialogArgs: BeginSkillDialogOptions = {
                 activity: activity as Activity
            };
            await innerDc.beginDialog(EvaConfig.LUIS_DEFAULT_INTENT, skillDialogArgs);
       } else {
            await innerDc.cancelAllDialogs();
       }

       // code for starting LiveChat goes here

       // .....
       // .....
       // .....
  }

MainDialog.ts in Skill
```

If activity.type is EVENT and name is 'liveChat', cancel dialogs.

```
protected async onContinueDialog(innerDc: DialogContext): Promise<DialogTurnResult> {

    try {
        let activity = innerDc.context.activity;
        if (innerDc.context.activity.type === ActivityTypes.Message) {
             // .....
             // .....
             // .....
        } else if (activity.type === ActivityTypes.Event) {
            const ev = activity;
            if (ev.name !== undefined && ev.name.trim().length > 0) {
                switch (ev.name) {
                    case 'liveChat': {
                        await innerDc.cancelAllDialogs(true);
                        return await innerDc.endDialog();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return await super.onContinueDialog(innerDc);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(`Error onContinueDialog ---> ${e} `);
        return await this.hanldeException(innerDc);
    }
}
```

**Issue**

The above code is not able to cancel the skill's dialog correctly. If we try to start a new dialog after the cancellation of skill dialog, it again sends an activity with activity.type as EVENT to routeStep method of MainDilaog.ts in Skill. Please find the sample code below for the same.

```
routeStep method of MainDialog.ts in Skill

protected async routeStep(stepContext: WaterfallStepContext): Promise<DialogTurnResult> {
    console.log('skill routeStep');
    if (activity.type === ActivityTypes.Message && activity.text !== undefined && activity.text.trim().length > 0) {
         // .....
         // .....
         // .....
    } else if (activity.type === ActivityTypes.Event) {
            const ev = activity;
            if (ev.name !== undefined && ev.name.trim().length > 0) {
                switch (ev.name) {
                    case 'SampleAction': {
                    // .....
                        // .....
                        // .....
                    }
                }
            } else {

                // If we try to start a new dialog, control comes here

                await stepContext.context.sendActivity({
                    type: ActivityTypes.Trace,
                    text: 'An event with no name was received but not processed.'
                });
            }
        }
    } else {
        await this.responder.replyWith(stepContext.context, MainResponses.responseIds.dontHavePermissionServiceNow);
        await this.complete(stepContext);
    }
    return await stepContext.next();
```

}

Step to Reproduce

Step 1. Start a Dialog in Skill
Step 2. End the Dialog in the Skill and start a Dialog in VA
Step 3. Start a new Dialog

Thanks.
Edward